# Why SparseIndexVector in tflite schema is union?

Tags: tensorflow, flatbuffers, tensorflow-lite

Looking at the schema, I have a question. There is `SparseIndexVector` whose type is union.

```
union SparseIndexVector {
  Int32Vector,
  Uint16Vector,
  Uint8Vector
}
```

This is the sub-parameter of `SparsityParameters`. But I don't know why it should be union.

The only thing I could guess is a memory. Is there any other reason it must be a union, not just Int32Vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's designed this way to store the metadata of a sparse tensor as efficiently as possible. If the tensor itself is relatively small, it would be wasteful to store the indices with the int32 type. Also think about a quantized sparse tensor. If the metadata uses the int32 type blindly, it can easily gets larger than the tensor itself.

Comment: I get the picture. Thanks:)